# How can I solve error?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I'm programming on objective-c and I've got this error, how can I solve it?

```
CompileC DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/Objects-normal/i386/ioapi-B8F5CE0D70C54AA1.o ioapi.c normal i386 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -iquote /Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/MyBook-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/MyBook-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/MyBook-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/MyBook-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -I/Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/SDWebImage -I/Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -include /Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MyBook-Prefix-ejgtcvngmdefurdjssqldbeazpbs/MyBook-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/Objects-normal/i386/ioapi-B8F5CE0D70C54AA1.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/Objects-normal/i386/ioapi-B8F5CE0D70C54AA1.dia -c /Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/ioapi.c -o /Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/DerivedData/MyBook/Build/Intermediates/MyBook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyBook.build/Objects-normal/i386/ioapi-B8F5CE0D70C54AA1.o

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/kilovata/Documents/Projects/MyBook/ioapi.c'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: This is way to vague without code or a formatted error String. I have no doubt this question is a few minutes from being closed.

Comment: If you don't tell something more about your problem you will get a lof of down votes!

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing exactly what it is your error is, in general one can figure out how to fix compilation/linker errors by performing the following steps:

1. Click ( or double click ) the error in your error view (depends on IDE) and this should take you to the applicable area in your code the error applies to.
2. If step 1 doesn't take you anywhere (likely for linker errors) or you aren't sure why that line is producing an error, try googling the exact error message, and look through the results to see if they help.
3. If all else fails, you can come on SO and post the MINIMUM required to describe your error.  Posting your entire build log is not really accepted by the community here

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't assigned the source files to any Xcode targets.

To solve:

- Highlight each source file in the project explorer (left pane).
- Open the right-pane and select the leftmost tab.
- Select the target the source file belongs to.